# How to send the visualization objects like bar graphs and charts in azure function API

Tags: python, azure-functions, langchain, azure-openai

I have just written a code for a CSV data analysis using the langchain and openai it gives text results also if a user asks for charts results it will provide but how to send the result in API?

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
try:
    req_body = req.get_json()
    query = req_body.get('query')
    if not query:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'query' parameter in the request.",
            status_code=400
        )        
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    csv_files = [blob.name for blob in blob_list if blob.name.lower().endswith('.csv')]
    latest_csv = max(csv_files, key=lambda blob_name: container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name).get_blob_properties().last_modified)
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_filename = temp_file.name
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(latest_csv)
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        temp_file.write(blob_data.readall())
    df = pd.read_csv(temp_filename)
    df = df.replace(0, np.nan)      
    agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
        ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, engine="gpt3516k"),
        df,
        verbose=True,
        agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
        )
    result = agent.run(query)
    image_bytes = "No result"
    final_result = json.dumps({"text":[{"message":query,"text_response": result,"sources":"","suggested_queries":"","graph":image_bytes}]})
    return func.HttpResponse(final_result, mimetype='application/json')
except Exception as e:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        f"An error occurred: {str(e)}",
        status_code=500
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried below code to visualize the data and send graph via Azure Functions with openai and langchain:-**

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import os
import json
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openai
import base64

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import azure.functions as func


openai.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxSXztIWL0Pz"

def fetch_latest_csv_from_blob(azure_connection_string, container_name):
    azure_connection_string = os.environ["AzureWebJobsStorage"]
    container_name = "test"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    csv_files = [blob.name for blob in blob_list if blob.name.lower().endswith('.csv')]
    latest_csv = max(csv_files, key=lambda blob_name: container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name).get_blob_properties().last_modified)
    
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_filename = temp_file.name
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(latest_csv)
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        temp_file.write(blob_data.readall())
    
    return temp_filename

def generate_sample_chart(data, chart_filename):
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.xlabel('X-axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
    plt.title('Sample Chart')
    plt.savefig(chart_filename, format='png')

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        query = req_body.get('query')
        if not query:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Please provide a 'query' parameter in the request.",
                status_code=400
            )        

        azure_connection_string = os.environ["AzureWebJobsStorage"]
        container_name = "test"

        
        temp_filename = fetch_latest_csv_from_blob(azure_connection_string, container_name)

        df = pd.read_csv(temp_filename)
        df = df.replace(0, np.nan)

        
        data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
        chart_filename = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".png")
        generate_sample_chart(data, chart_filename)

        
        result = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=query,
            max_tokens=50  
        )

       
        with open(chart_filename, 'rb') as chart_file:
            chart_base64 = base64.b64encode(chart_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

        final_result = json.dumps({"text": [{"message": query, "text_response": result.choices[0].text, "sources": "", "suggested_queries": "", "graph": chart_base64}]})
        return func.HttpResponse(final_result, mimetype='application/json')
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"An error occurred: {str(e)}",
            status_code=500
        )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Passed below query in the body of the Postman API request:-

```json
{
  "query": "Generate a bar chart that represents the sales data for the last quarter."
}
```

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
pandas
numpy
matplotlib
openai
```

**Postman Output:-**

I have selected visualize output section in Postman like below:-

[image]

[image]

I copied the entire base64 content of "graph": and decoded it into png via this [website](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/png) and received graph output like below:-

[image]